# Error "The type or namespace name 'DotNetOpenAuth' could not be found" in VS2013 but not VS2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have a ASP.NET MVC 3 project, which uses DotNetOpenAuth, retrieved via NuGet. Package restore is enabled. The project uses .NET 4 (the full profile, not client).

In Visual Studio 2012, the project compiles and runs fine.

In Visual Studio 2013, I get the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'DotNetOpenAuth' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The DLLs are successfully restored to the `packages` folder, and are also correctly copied to the `bin` folder of the website project. All appropriate `using`s have been added. Each time I have tested a change from a clean working directory. All of the other projects in the solution compile fine. The assembly references look like this in the `Website.csproj` file:

```
<Reference Include="DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\DotNetOpenAuth.Core.4.3.1.13153\lib\net40-full\DotNetOpenAuth.Core.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that an import had been accidentally removed from the project file at some point. Installing DotNetOpenAuth via NuGet adds a dependency on the Microsoft BCL build components, resulting in the following line in your project file:

```
<Import Project="..\..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.8\tools\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets" />
```

In my project, this line had been removed (possibly because it seemed unnecessary). VS2012 worked fine without this import, but VS2013 didn't.

Answer (score 4):

To install DotNetOpenAuth extensions for ASP.NET (WebPages), run the following command in the Package Manager Console

PM> Install-Package DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet